# Scheduler not running Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I'm trying to run a scheduler that grabs bitcoin prices every minute and add them to a database, but I can't get the larval scheduler to run properly.

I've tested the sql code in a separate php page and it works but the scheduler doesn't seem to be running

Schedule function is in kernel.php
Handle function is in Jobs/UpdateRates

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\UpdateRates)->everyMinute();

}


public function handle()
{
    $url = "https://bitpay.com/api/rates";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    $rate = $data[1]["rate"];    
    $usd_price = 10;     # Let cost of elephant be 10$
    $bitcoin_price = round( $usd_price / $rate , 8 );

    DB::insert('insert into settings (bitcoin_rate, monero_rate) values (?, ?)', [0, 1]);
}
```

Comment: what is the output of the job without scheduler, I mean if you run it using `php artisan tinker` does it work?

Comment: after running it with `tinker`, does it insert any record in the database?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but what do you have triggering your scheduled tasks?

Comment: Have you added the cron job?

Comment: @MichaelMiller & cmac I might be dumb saying this, but I thought that's what the line in kernel.php did lol     $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\UpdateRates)->everyMinute();

Comment: Don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to cron:

> vim /etc/crontab

Fix **path-to-your-project**, add this line

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This is what calls Laravel and then you can do the rest of your scheduling from within the Laravel Project.

And now you can just add tasks like this and not have to worry about updating cron again.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new DailyEmailReports)->dailyAt();
    $schedule->job(new SomeOtherThing)->hourly();
    $schedule->job(new SomeElse)->everyFiveMinutes();     
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I don't understand what is point of the "->everyMinute();" part in kernel.php if I had to use a cron anyways

Comment: Well, now you can add more and more $schedule->command(SomeCommand::class)->daily();
$schedule->command(OtherCommand::class)->everyFiveMinutes();

Comment: Does that make more sense @JohnPooder?

Comment: No I don't understand what you are saying

Comment: Basically **cron** is how your server does stuff every xxx (seconds, minutes, etc..). The line you add to cron is running **php artisan schedule:run, etc, etc...** every millisecond or so I believe and now inside of your Laravel Project you can setup tasks and run them every minute, hour, etc... all by just adding another:
    $schedule->job(new SomeNewTask)->everyFiveMinutes();
And not having to add another line to cron. Does that make better sense?

Comment: So by adding that line to cron, you can now use Laravels **Task Scheduler** 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#introduction
Instead of using your servers cron to schedule things.